# Assumption of Shor's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the assumption of Shor's algorithm (wiki), there says that we need to check that there are no integer roots for $\sqrt[k] N$ for $2\le k\le log_3^N$. I can't realize why the upper bound is $log_3^N$. Take 8 for example. The upper bound is smaller than 2. I can't convince myself this criterion. Could someone give me some hints? Thank you!!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm

Comment: You have copied that incorrectly.  The inequality is 
$$
2 \leq k \leq \log_3(N)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of the initial test is not explained clearly on the wiki page.  There are two separate steps here: first, we check whether $N$ is even. This can be done by computing $N \bmod 2$, i.e. `N % 2`.  Your example of $N = 8$ would fail to pass this test.

In the second step, we check whether $N$ is of the form $q^k$ for any $k \geq 2$; $q$ need not be prime.  Since any $N$ that passed the first test is odd, we know that $N$ would necessarily have to be a power of a number $q$ with $q \geq 3$.  To check whether $N$ is a prime number, we check whether $\sqrt[k]{N}$ is a whole number for any $k$ with $2 \leq k \leq \log_3(N)$.

Here is why this range of values for $k$ is sufficient.  Of course $k=2$ is the smallest value that we need to consider.  On the other hand, 
$$
N = q^k \implies \log_3(N) = \log_3(q^k) = k \log_3(q) \implies \\
k = \frac{\log_3(N)}{\log_3(q)} \leq \frac{\log_3(N)}{\log_3(3)} = \log_3(N).
$$
If $N$ passes both of these tests, we can be sure that $N$ is not even and that $N$ does not satisfy $N = p^k$ for any prime number $p$.